# Geography in a social network

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I want to make a global social network, in which users can search for nearby users.

What is the preferred way to allow users to easily specify where they are located?

Zip code would be accurate, but is US-only.

Lat/long would be accurate, but it is too difficult for mom and dad types.

Drop-down menu of continent, country, province, major city is simple, but perhaps not that accurate if someone lives somewhere remote or in between two major cities.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I am not the mom-and-dad type, but I would never enter two floating point numbers on any app! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an API to convert addresses to latitude/longitudes.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_exists

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Comment: That's not my question. My question isn't how to convert an address to a lat/long.

My question is what is the most idiot-proof user interface to get a user's address within a few miles.

Comment: Provide them with a text box to type in their address.  Pass that into the API and get a latitude/longitude.

Comment: @turian: the answer is pertinent. Put a textbox, let them drop in their address, then geocode it. And let them the ability to edit the address: google geocoding can often resolve to nothing and/or to north pole.

Comment: +1. You could show them the result on a map and let them drag their "You Are Here" marker to tweak the results if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

[Using Java and any external libraries, how can I draw latitude/longitude points onto a graphical representation of the Earth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110074/using-java-and-any-external-libraries-how-can-i-draw-latitude-longitude-points-o)

There is google API for same .

Answer (score 0):

What about using their ip address to locate their location. It isn't best solution compared to google geocoding, but not a bad one i guess.

This might help

[IP2Location Application](http://www.ip2location.com/free.asp)

for more google "location by ip address + api"

Cheers